# Obtaining last value of column for each row, with unequal length of rows in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     A       B        C     D       E   F 
  0  Jack    Sales    23    Happy
  1  NaN     John     Acc.  45      Sad
  2  Maria   Eng.     34    Happy
  3  NaN     Maria    STEM  56      Sad
  4  NaN     NaN      Paul  Lawyer  80  Happy
```

As you can see, data is quite messy to work with: `NaN` is all over the DataFrame.

I just need to use the last value of each row (i.e., `Happy` or `Sad`), so I started trying to "extract" that last value, but I got nowhere.

I did my research but everything I googled seems to be how to extract the *last row* from a **specific** column, while what I need is more like "for each row, extract the last value, **no matter** in which column it is".

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ffill` after cleaning your dataframe:

```
out = df.replace('', np.NaN).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print(out)

# Output
0    Happy
1      Sad
2    Happy
3      Sad
4    Happy
Name: F, dtype: object
```